# Hide an iOS button when it is pressed

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, show-hide

I have defined a button in my Storyboard. I have then defined it in my .h file as an `IBAction`, and connected it to the button from the storyboard.

I want it to be hidden by default, and also when I tap it once, it should hide itself.
I'm not having any luck trying to hide it.

This is what my code looks like right now. There's an error thrown:

> Property `hidden` not found on object of type CounterViewController

```
- (IBAction)retry:(id)sender 
{
    self.hidden=TRUE;
}
```

Comment: please use like: [self.ButtonName setHidden:true];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
 - (IBAction)retry:(id)sender {
     ((UIButton *)sender).hidden=YES;
 }
```

Comment: It works! Is there a line of code I can call in another function to make it visible again?

Comment: If you hold a reference to your button, just do: myButton.hidden = NO; Please accept the answer if it worked!

Comment: @P.Sami. It's method of `UIView`. `UIButton` is subclass of `UIView`.

Comment: `[((UIButton*)sender) setHidden:(BOOL)];`

Comment: `- (IBAction)retry:(id)sender` is the only point of reference for the button in the code. How exactly do I reference it? `retry.hidden = NO;` doesn't work.

Comment: You can also use following

Answer (score 1):

You can also use following

```
- (IBAction)retry:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    sender.hidden=YES;
}
```

Comment: Typing the method's parameter as `UIButton *` rather than casting makes this answer better than the accepted answer.